# Access a specific listview item, to edit it

Tags: android, listview

I need to access a specific item in listview (compiled by a simplecursoradapter).
I need to edit this item layout, I've done it in the setscrolllistener but here (in the creation) it impossible.

My code:

```
    RelativeLayout item2 = (RelativeLayout) lista.getChildAt(3);
    RelativeLayout da_cambiare=(RelativeLayout)item2.findViewById(R.id.elemento_contenitore);
    da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_1);
    switch(mese_numero){
        case 1:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_1);
            break;
        case 2:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_2);
            break;
        case 3:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_3);
            break;
        case 4:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_4);
            break;
        case 5:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_5);
            break;
        case 6:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_6);
            break;
        case 7:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_7);
            break;
        case 8:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_8);
            break;
        case 9:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_9);
            break;
        case 10:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_10);
            break;
        case 11:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_11);
            break;
        case 12:
            da_cambiare.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sfondo_elemento_lista_12);
            break;
    }
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    da_cambiare.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/guscio_elemento"
android:layout_height="57dp">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo_elemento_lista"
    android:id="@+id/elemento_contenitore"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/elemento_id"
        android:layout_height="28dp" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/elemento_titolo"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#868686"
        android:layout_height="28dp" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/elemento_piu"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="+"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#868686"
        android:layout_height="28dp" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/elemento_titolo"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="6">
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:id="@+id/elemento_1"
            android:background="#b04a74"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:id="@+id/elemento_2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="#007987"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/elemento_3"
            android:background="#dda00a"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.2"
            android:id="@+id/elemento_numero"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#868686"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get a nullpointer at the second line. I don't know why, because (I repeat) the exact same code works in the setOnScrollListener onScrollStateChanged.

Comment: you get null pointer because `item2` is null. Most probably items are not created yet

Comment: Your question is unclear, which makes it difficult to help. It is obvious that you are facing trivial problem, but without more transparent explanation you are unlikely to get useful help.

Comment: I don't know what explanation do you want: it's a listview, and i need to access the layout of that item to edit it (remove margin, change background).

Comment: mihail you're right! i don't know how to accept your question, but i've integrated a handler that make the function after a second. and it' all ok! thanks!